# If I add a reference to a dll in VS2010, will that dll be packaged up with my app when I deploy?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

If I add a reference in Visual Studio 2010 to a .dll file, will that .dll file be packaged up with my application when I deploy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, yes.

To make sure it'll always be copied to the output directory, right click the DLL and select `Copay Local = True` in the Properties grid.

> Copy Local = Indicates whether the reference will be copied to the
>   output directory

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Leniel!  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as the timer is up.  Again, thank you!  I greatly appreciate it.